# polymorphism is a bottom-up method call?

Tags: java, oop

I have seen general discussions on OOP and Java with the statement "polymorphism is just a bottom-up method call." It is not clear to me how is it so.  An example would help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Top {
   void foo() {...}
}
class Middle extends Top
class Bottom extends Middle
```

Consider method `foo()` that is present in `Top` but can be also in `Middle` or `Bottom`. If you have object declared as type `Top`

```
Top obj = ...
```

You can always call method `foo()` on it. However, `obj` may be of type `Bottom` as well, so in polymorphic case you will call `foo()` on `Bottom` and if `Bottom` does not have `foo()` you call it on `Middle` and if `Middle` does not have it, you call it on `Top`.

So your method call goes from `Bottom` to `Top` in a way...

Comment: The distinction between static and dynamic types is crucial for polymorphism. Hence I'd appreciate more care on that issue - specifically, the variable `obj` is always of the type `Top` ("static type"), but the object it refers to actually be an instance of a subclass ("dynamic type"). The latter decides which method is called (when polymorphism is in place).